# vue components wont load

Tags: laravel-5, vue.js

I try to work with vuejs in laravel, I installed `npm` `vue-router` `vue-axios` but when i try to load my page i get console error like: `ReferenceError: CreateCategory is not defined` and empty page.

here is my `app.js`:

```
require('./bootstrap');

window.Vue = require('vue');

import VueRouter from 'vue-router';
Vue.use(VueRouter);

import VueAxios from 'vue-axios';
import axios from 'axios';
Vue.use(VueAxios, axios);


import App from './App.vue';
Vue.component('CreateCategory', require('./components/CreateCategory.vue'));
Vue.component('DisplayCategory', require('./components/DisplayCategory.vue'));
Vue.component('EditCategory', require('./components/EditCategory.vue'));


const routes = [
  {
    name: 'CreateCategory',
    path: '/categories/create',
    component: CreateCategory
  },
  {
    name: 'DisplayCategory',
    path: '/',
    component: DisplayCategory
  },
  {
    name: 'EditCategory',
    path: '/edit/:id',
    component: EditCategory
   }
];



const router = new VueRouter({ mode: 'history', routes: routes});
new Vue(Vue.util.extend({ router }, App)).$mount('#app');

// const app = new Vue({
//   router,
//   render: h => h(App)
// });

// const app = new Vue({
//     el: '#app'
// });
```

PS: I read articles about component in router and I already tried with `.default` that won't work neither they only good of that was i didn't get console error.

## UPDATE

my `CreateCategory.vue` component:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <h1>Create A Category</h1>
    <form v-on:submit.prevent="addCategory">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label>Category Title:</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" v-model="category.title">
          </div>
        </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label>Category Status:</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control col-md-6" v-model="category.status" />
            </div>
          </div>
        </div><br />
        <div class="form-group">
          <button class="btn btn-primary">Add Category</button>
        </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    data(){
        return{
          category:{}
        }
    },
    methods: {
      addCategory(){
        let uri = 'http://localhost/vuetjd/public/categories';
        this.axios.post(uri, this.category).then((response) => {
          this.$router.push({title: 'DisplayCategory'})
        })
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: `component: CreateCategory` references a variable, `CreateCategory`, that you have not defined.

Comment: but im trying to load DisplayCategory page! and as i said with . default error will gone

Comment: You should typically just be doing `component: require('./components/CreateCategory.vue')` (for each of those routes). Doesn't matter which route you're loading - all the JS gets parsed, and you have an error in it.

Comment: in routes you mean?

Comment: @ceejayoz i've changed my routes as you said, error is gone but still i see blank page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found what is the issue, I'm suppose to run `php artisan serve` to be able to see my data. if just open my url i'll get blanck page but with `serve` i get my data as well.

Comment: how to run without `php artisan serve` ?

Comment: If you are using laragon as server i suggest to restart your system once. If you have skype installed uninstall it and set your server to use port 80. If none of them worked or just keep using serve command or hope someday it resolved by itself that's all i have in my experience.

Comment: @MasterpieceMasIcang Oh i forgot to mention, check your localhost settings in env file probably you have to use ip address instead of localhost as host name.

Answer (score 1):

`CreateCategory.vue` is a Single File Component.

In there, you must have a `export default {}`, where `{}` is actually the Component Object.

What you have to do, is that, you need to import the `CreateCategory.vue` and then assign it, like so:

```
import CreateCategory from './components/CreateCategory.vue';

const routes = [
  {
    name: 'CreateCategory',
    path: '/categories/create',
    component: CreateCategory
  }
];
```

now this will work.
you have to do the same for `DisplayCategory` and `EditCategory`.

Comment: Hi, I updated my question now you can see my component as well.

Comment: do you still have a problem?

Comment: no man thank you. i needed to use artisan serve which is totally unnecessary , i changed my local host setting and now i can see changes even without using artisan serve.